# Tailwind CSS in Next js working in Localhost but not working In production

Tags: next.js, tailwind-css

Tailwind CSS in Next js working in Localhost but not working In production.using scss

Everything works fine in localhost but code fails in production

package.json

```html
{
  "name": "app-name",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start -p $PORT",
    "heroku-postbuild": "npm run build",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "framer-motion": "^6.2.6",
    "next": "12.1.0",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "17.0.2",
    "react-icons": "^4.3.1",
    "sass": "^1.49.8",
    "swiper": "^8.0.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.2",
    "eslint": "8.9.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "12.1.0",
    "postcss": "^8.4.6",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.0.23"
  }
}
```

tailwind.config.js

```html
module.exports = {
  content: ["./pages/**/*.js", "./components/**/*.js"],

  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
};
```

postcss.config.js

```html
module.exports = {
  plugins: {
    tailwindcss: {},
    autoprefixer: {},
  },
};
```

Comment: Rather than recompiling after production, why not just use the already compiled working css produced during development on localhost and include them in your html header for production?

Comment: How is it possible. Any demos?

Comment: When run the scss preprocessor during dev on localhost, the output css file must reside somewhere on your local machine. Copy these output files to your production server public folder or any other  folder as required by your server configuration. You can then include them as header links in your html.

Comment: Can you share your project's folder structure?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I have the same issue.